# Change element inside Template

Tags: wpf, xaml, templates, itemscontrol

I want to reuse the the ItemsControl from my ListView and its not really hard to put the ItemsControle into an Template.
The problem is, I want to change the DataTemplate when I use my ItemsControlTemplate.

```
<ListView DataContext="{Binding Input}">
                        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Columns}">
                            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Grid>
                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <RowDefinition/>
                                            <RowDefinition/>
                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0">
                                            <Label Content="{Binding ColumnHeader}"></Label>
                                        </StackPanel>
                                        <ListView Grid.Row="1">
                                            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ColumnData}">
                                                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>

                                                    <!--This should be changed when I reuse my ItemsControl-->
                                                    <DataTemplate>
                                                        <Button Content="{Binding}"/>
                                                    </DataTemplate>


                                                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                            </ItemsControl>
                                        </ListView>
                                    </Grid>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl>
                    </ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Resource` to set that `ItemTemplate` dynamically. Just provide a default `Resource` of `DataTemplate`, when you need to change it, override that resource (using the same key and place in a closer place to the control).

```
 <ListView Grid.Row="1">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ColumnData}"
                  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource templateKey}"/>
 </ListView>
```

Then define a resource with `x:Key` of `templateKey` like this:

```
 <Window.Resources>
   <DataTemplate x:Key="templateKey">
     <Button Content="{Binding}"/>
   </DataTemplate>
 <Window.Resources>
```

Here is an example of overriding the template, in which we place another `DataTemplate` inside the `ListView`'s Resources:

```
<ListView DataContext="{Binding Input}">
   <ListView.Resources>
     <DataTemplate x:Key="templateKey">
       <CheckBox Content="{Binding}"/>
     </DataTemplate>
   </ListView.Resources>
   <!-- ... -->
</ListView>
```

If you want to update the template at runtime, you need to use `DynamicResource` instead of `StaticResource`.