# How to change resource template element's property using only XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

The main idea is to have a button with default icon `"yes.png"` and text in it `"Accept"`, but have a possibilty to change these two properties using only XAML(at the designing process, without compiling).

Current XAML window which has an area at the bottom with only two buttons:

```
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Style x:Key="tb1" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#000" Padding="0">
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <Image Source="Files/Icons/no.png" Margin="10,0,0,0" Height="16" Width="16"></Image>
                                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Margin="10" VerticalAlignment="Center">Cancel</TextBlock>
                                </Grid>
                            </Border>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,10,10,10"></Setter>
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Border BorderThickness="0, 1, 0, 0" BorderBrush="#e7e7e7" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Padding="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Height="61">
            <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                <Button x:Name="b_Accept" Style="{StaticResource tb1}"></Button> <!-- How to change an icon to "yes.png" and TextBlock's content to "Accept"? -->
                <Button x:Name="b_Cancel" Style="{StaticResource tb1}"></Button>
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Result:

[image: img1]

Please,

1. How is it possible to change second button's icon to `"no.png"`(**Source property**) and TextBlock's text(**Content**) to `"Cancel"`(**only using XAML** and **not User Control**)?
2. What would be the **very right way**(the easiest?)? For example, in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26329471/5113030) we might use **DataTemplate**, but might be that's not that we want to because DataTemplate changes the whole element, while we need only one property.

Although, I am right that there are only `dependency property`(C#) available for that purpose which expects compiling?

Thank you

Comment: A button is a contentcontrol. It already has a content dependency property you can use to change it's content. You could do that via datatemplate or datatrigger using xaml. I would consider that approach before an attached property. Unless there's some other reason for an attached dp. Wpf has very lightweight components allow you to use vector based iconography - such as paths and geometries. These are usually preferable to bitmap based pictures such as png.

Comment: @Andy Okay, so `Content` might be changed for Button out of box, but what about inner elements?

Comment: You can have content controls inside a template but i don't see a need here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your custom `Button` class or an Attached Property to extend the `Button`:

```
public class IconControl : DependencyObject
{
  #region IconUri attached property

  public static readonly DependencyProperty IconUriProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
    "IconUri", typeof(ImageSource), typeof(IconControl), new PropertyMetadata(default(ImageSource)));

  public static void SetIconUri([NotNull] DependencyObject attachingElement, ImageSource value)
  {
    attachingElement.SetValue(IconControl.IconUriProperty, value);
  }

  public static ImageSource GetIconUri([NotNull] DependencyObject attachingElement) => (ImageSource) attachingElement.GetValue(IconControl.IconUriProperty);

  #endregion

  #region Label attached property

  public static readonly DependencyProperty LabelProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
    "Label", typeof(String), typeof(IconControl), new PropertyMetadata(default(String)));

  public static void SetLabel([NotNull] DependencyObject attachingElement, String value)
  {
    attachingElement.SetValue(IconControl.LabelProperty, value);
  }

  public static String GetLabel([NotNull] DependencyObject attachingElement) => (String) attachingElement.GetValue(IconControl.LabelProperty);

  #endregion
}
```

Modified `Style` for the `Button`:

```
<Style x:Key="IconButtonStyle"
       TargetType="{x:Type Button}">

  <!-- Set the default values -->
  <Setter Property="IconControl.IconUri" Value="/Files/Icons/no.png"/>
  <Setter Property="IconControl.Label" Value="Cancel"/>

  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Border BorderThickness="1"
                BorderBrush="#000"
                Padding="0">
          <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
              <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
              <ColumnDefinition />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Image Source="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=(IconControl.IconUri)}"
                   Margin="10,0,0,0"
                   Height="16"
                   Width="16" />
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"
                       Margin="10"
                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                       Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=(IconControl.Label)}" />
          </Grid>
        </Border>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
  <Setter Property="Margin"
          Value="0,10,10,10"></Setter>
</Style>
```

Usage:

```
<!-- Override the default content -->
<Button Style="{StaticResource IconButtonStyle}"
        IconControl.IconUri="/Files/Icons/yes.png"
        IconControl.Label="Accept" />
```

Comment: This requires C# compilation. Is it possible without using `Dependency Property`?

Comment: For now it says "IconControl is not supported in a Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) project." in XAML design window.

Comment: You have to qualify the namespace of the type e.g., `myNamespace:IconControl.Label="Accept"`. This is typical for all xaml objects.

Comment: What do you mean by "requires compilation"? You always have to compile the code whether it's C# or XAML. Windows can't execute .xaml files.

Comment: By the meaning of C# compilation, it won't let viewing the result instantly live in design window.

Comment: In my opinion this is a bad criteria for a design decision. But anyway, modifying the Attached Property will update the XAML Designer view immediately. Just try it.

Comment: This works when compiling and running, but currently live preview shows https://i.imgur.com/NIMhC2t.png

Comment: I just tested it and I can't reproduce it. I can change the image and the label and the designer will immediately show both changes. Maybe you have some issues with your image resources?

Comment: Strange thing. After your comment I've tried restarting Visual Studio 2019 16.3.4 and it showed them corretly in live designer! https://y2u.be/ld2nWfIap2k